# unable to Add display data values on top of bar high chart

Tags: highcharts

as i am trying with above displayed code, but unable to get data values over bar chart
 i want data values to be displayed over bars. when i tried it by adding datalabels value get displayed in the bar not on the bar .please help in this regard.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4]

        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `dataLabels: { enabled: true }` under plotOptions. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/499/